# Deploying an Azure Container Instance Failing: OsVersionNotSupported

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.1 web app; I'm trying to deploy an instance of its container from a Container Registry.  However, when I select to deploy to instance, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "OsVersionNotSupported",
    "message": "The OS version of image 'webapplication123456.azurecr.io/webapplication:latest' is not supported."
}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to identify exactly what the issue is.  The container is a Windows container, and I'm deploying as such.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware ACI only supports plain 2016 base images, not 1703\1709\1803 os images.

Probably no 2019 yet as well

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of supported (or not supported) images from Azure itself?

Comment: well, basically anything linux should be supported, for windows its 2016, but I dont know of such an API

Comment: There is no such API but you can get cached images list with help of [API] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/container-instances/listcachedimages/listcachedimages)